# Python example to create a depth map from point clouds with camera intrinsic

Tags: python, opencv, projection, point-clouds, open3d

I've seen plenty of opencv code in c++ about how to convert a 3d point cloud to a depth map, with camera intrinsics(matrix and with width, height, fx, fy, cx, and cy), but I have not seen any code about convert a point cloud to a depth map with python. I've tried using open3d, which works well when converting from a depth image to a point cloud, but when converting from point cloud to depth map, I get a heatmap, which randomly scales, so when I reimport from a depth map to a point cloud in open3d, the depth map is  incorrect(since I had to convert from heatmap to depthmap), and the depth map does not line up with the rgb image.
Here is my code in open3d to convert rgb and a depthmap to a point cloud in open3d?

```
intrinsics = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(640, 480 ,525.0, 525.0, 319.5, 239.5) 
'''
width (int) – Width of the image.

height (int) – Height of the image.

fx (float) – X-axis focal length

fy (float) – Y-axis focal length.

cx (float) – X-axis principle point.

cy (float) – Y-axis principle point.
'''
depth_raw = o3d.io.read_image("./00000.png")
color_raw = o3d.io.read_image("./color.jpg")
rgbd_image = create_rgbd_image_from_color_and_depth(
    color_raw, depth_raw)

pcd =  o3d.geometry.create_point_cloud_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(intrinsics))
pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]) # flips to it is right side up
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
np.savetxt("./pcd.txt", np.asarray(pcd.points))
```

Could someone help me out with code to project a point cloud to a depth map, in python, in either opencv or with any other library.